# Trilogy of books about dragon souls inhabiting humans normally warriors

Tags: books, dragons, story-identification

It has been a long time since I read the first book but will remember what I can. There were dragons, but they could not survive alone; they needed human hosts, and were beneficial to the human. There was a war going on. I remember, at the end of the first book, the dragon was looking for a new host and he flew over a crippled girl, and she asked him to save her, but the dragon scorned her and looked for someone stronger.

Comment: Dragon spirits inhabiting humans is actually a pretty tropey trope; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13516062-immortal-coil

Comment: And this; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21803200-kindling-ashes

Comment: You mention "Japan" in your tags. Do you remember the book as being set there? And when was "a long time ago"?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the book was set in Japan although cannot be 100% I read the book over ten years ago. The main character was a man who was nobody before the dragon but ended up with a big castle. I have a strange feeling the author was female

Comment: Dragon souls in people? Sounds like Skyrim Lore books to me.

Answer (score 6):

A series of books that come to mind are a trilogy by Joanne Bertin; *The Last Dragonlord*, *Dragon and Phoenix* and *Bard's Oath*. The humans share a soul with dragons and can shape shift into them. The Dragonlords act as judges/mediators for the kingdoms. There is the prospect of a civil war happening because of a royal assassination. The youngest dragonlord, if I remember correctly, was a common warrior before becoming becoming twin souled.The woman who's becomes the next dragonlord at the end of the book is not crippled, but in the second book is unable to shift. Also a good deal of the second book happens in a land that resembles China[image] [image]

Comment: I will look this up as it sounds like it could be the one.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*Eon: Rise of the Dragoneye*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Eon-Rise-Dragoneye-Alison-Goodman/dp/184992001X) (2008) by Alison Goodman, also known as [*The Two Pearls of Wisdom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Pearls_of_Wisdom)?

It was a duology rather than a trilogy but the plot seems to fit. The blurb mentions dragons co-habiting humans and a crippled girl:

> Twelve-year old Eon has been studying the ancient art of the
>   Dragoneyes for two years. But he is playing a dangerous game: Eon is
>   actually Eona, 16 years old and a girl. Her true identity must remain
>   hidden at all costs: it is forbidden for women to practise the Art,
>   and to be discovered would be punishable by death.
>
> Let down by her injured leg, it seems that Eon is destined to fail in
>   her quest, until a spectacular twist in events catapults her into the
>   opulent but treacherous world of the Imperial court. Without a master
>   to guide her, Eon must learn to harness her unprecedented natural
>   power, while protecting the secret that could cost her everything . .
>   .
>
> Set against a rich backdrop of Ancient Chinese myths and traditions
>   and fraught with tension, this is a classic page-turner.

Comment: There were definitely three books as I borrowed them from a friend who moved away before I read the third book which is why I want to find them. Also the girl was not a main character until book 2.

Comment: The books went through multiple renamings which could be what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it's the [Dragonback](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OD6K9W) zeries by Timothy Zahn. In the first book,

> When another ship crashes after a fierce battle, Jack rescues the sole
>   survivor-- a K'da warrior names Draycos, a dragonlike being who cannot live 
>   apart from a symbiotic relationship with a humanoid host

by allowing him to bond, as a two-dimensional image/tattoo, on his skin. This bonding was required for the K'da to survive long-term (they could leave short-term).

Don't remember a crippled girl being passed over, however. And it was in future Space, not Japan. But it did involve a dragon. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of [*The Tears of Artamon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tears_of_Artamon) series, in which dragons live inside human hosts, making the host considerably more powerful but slowly changing them from humans into dragons.

The crippled girl is Karila, who begged Khezef to take her but was refused. The main character you mentioned in a comment would be Gavril Andar, who was a nobody who received the dragon and was revealed as heir to the throne of Azkhendir, and indeed, got a big castle. The war was ongoing for much of the trilogy, and yes, the author was female. Not sure about Japan though.